# What is a modal view?

Tags: iphone, animation, pushviewcontroller

I wanted to do bottom-up or up-bottom animation for settings page. (which would normally be `pushViewController`)
And found out that bottom-up can be done with..

```
- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Some people seem to suggest that you stick to Apple's HIG (Apple surely made left-right animation as default pushViewController) and do not use modal view.

I wonder what is modal view and wonder what other animations people use for pushing/popping viewController?

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A modal view prevents interaction with any other UI until it is dismissed.

A modal view controller is simply a *UIViewController* class that is presented modally. When the view controller is presented modally it covers whatever the existing view was (using an animation if specified) and the user most somehow dismiss this view before they can return to what they were doing.

To present a view controller in a modal fashion, you can use the method:

```
- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Whenever I want to use a modal view (i.e. a view that must be completed before continuing with anything else) I would call this method and use Apple's standard animation for presenting a view controller (notice that the instance method above does not include a parameter to specify how the view is animated - because Apple has a standard way of doing this).

Comment: James, you say the modal view "covers up" the existing view. In some cases, it does not cover the existing view. However, it demands that the user interacts with it. An example is an alert that appears in the middle of the screen and asks the user to press Yes or No before that user can return to the previous view.

Comment: That's a really good point. I'll change the wording to state "covers". Clearly you cannot interact with the parent view though because one of the property's of the modal view controller's presentation is that it must be dismissed before you do anything else.

Comment: so modal view is.. 1. it must be deal with before you do anything else, 2... still confusing.. "modal" means, not complete by itself? .. not a native speaker here

Comment: There's a really good description on wikipedia for what "modal" means in this context. :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window